# How does one pass a parameter to an OData controller in LinqPad? i.e. http://localhost/vroot/odata/Foo('bar')

Tags: linq, odata, linqpad

I have a WebAPI OData web service that can optionally take a parameter.

I am using LinqPad to issue requests like:

```
from t in Foo
select t
```

Which is converted to this OData request:

```
http://my.localhost.com/vroot/odata/Foo()
```

*But I'd like to pass a parameter to Foo()* and get the following OData request:

```
http://my.localhost.com/vroot/odata/Foo('Bar')
```

This call works perfectly in the web browser.

Is this possible in LinqPad?  How is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from t in Foo
where t.Id=='Bar'
select t
```